# A grid of CUDA blocks Vs. a grid of MPI processes with a single block per process

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, mpi

Is there a difference in the efficiency when I launch N CUDA blocks from the one process in a CUDA grid and when I launch N MPI processes with one CUDA block per process, assuming no communication between blocks?

Comment: This depends entirely on the capabilities of the CPU and the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

As always: it depends.

If you are not using CUDA5, with a device `Hyper Q` capable, launch a grid CUDA grid in one process should be more efficient. Otherwise I can't tell, probably, the only way to be sure it's testing.

You may like to watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxtZwW2Lf-w), specially the part that Jen Hsun Huang speak about `Hyper Q`